# Ant JUnit Compile Q

Tags: junit3

i found this code snippet:

```
  <target name="test">
   <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <test name="${classes}" />
    <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
    <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
   </junit>
 </target>
```

Do I need to modify this to compile the test classes first, as opposed to running this target directly?

Answer (score 0):

jUnit can run .class OR .java files. You should not have to compile before running this test